# What does the notation $|B(x;\epsilon)|$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does the notation $|B(x,\epsilon)|$ mean? Is it the volume of the open ball? I saw it from the following:

> ...It follows from the Lebesgue theory that for almost every $x\in\Omega$, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,\epsilon)|} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(x) dx$ exists...

Comment: It means the volume (a.k.a Lebesgue measure) of the open ball.